# How can I tell if I am downloading/saving duplicate images?

Tags: windows, gratis, images

I am looking for a program for Windows that ideally works like Google Image Search however I want a program that scans a particular folder and compares all images in that folder that I choose or if I like, multiple folders of my choosing, visually compares these images and gives me a result of if these images are the same or not and tells me if these are duplicates however I want the program to give me an option to decide whether it is right or not as it may have accidentally assumed one image was a visual duplicate of another.

It should be....

- Free
- Lightweight
- Runs without administrative rights
- Takes up minimal computer space or memory
- Can visually compare images in a folder or multiple folders and you can either compare one folder of images with another and be able to scan them to see if there is the same of one image in folder A to folder X
- Accurate most of the time

Any suggestions/ideas? Hope it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Awesome Duplicate Photo Finder](http://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html):

- Free
- Pretty old so it should be lightweight Enough
- Can visually compare images in a folder or multiple folders:

[image]

PS: if you are willing to pay: [Visual Similarity Duplicate Images Finder](http://www.mindgems.com/products/VS-Duplicate-Image-Finder/VSDIF-About.htm).

Comment: Perfect. The other one needs admin permission though. This one doesn't because I am using it's portable version, but just what I was looking for thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [VSDIF](http://www.find-duplicates.com/Duplicate_Photo_Finder.html):

- free
- Can visually compare images in a folder or multiple folders:

[image]