# Command line tool to check whether two images are exactly the same graphically

Tags: linux, images, command-line

I need a command line tool that compares 2 images and says if their contents are the same, regardless of encoding - i.e. one might be a *.bmp and the other might be a *.png, so long as all their width, height and all the corresponding pixels are the same.

- Exact graphical sameness is needed
- Compression loss, even if nearly invisible, makes a different image
- Same alpha-transparency is also important
- EXIF/etc irrelevant

Comment: Just to clarify, the metadata (e.g. [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format)) is not relevant, right?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Yes, just that the images display the same on any background (i.e. alpha-transparency is a difference).

Answer (score 18):

With [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/) (`apt-get install imagemagick`), you can compare images independent of encoding and metadata like this:

```
identify -quiet -format "%#" images...
```

Note that images that have been encoded with **lossy compression** like **JPEG** (*.jpg) have subtle, often invisible changes.

See also [ImageMagick Examples: Image Signatures](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/).

Strictly speaking, you need to compare the color model, and scaling of pixel values, too. They may not be part of the metadata in the image.

Comment: Great answer. Just to clarify though: this will print concatenated checksums for each image in `images`. Then you need to check whether these checksums are the same.

Comment: Doesn't work when comparing two **visually identical** PNGs with one being palette (`8-bit colormap`) and the other full RGBA (`8-bit/color RGBA`). They don't show any difference with ImageMagick: `compare -dissimilarity-threshold 1 palette.png rgba.png difference.png` but these checksums are different.

Comment: @int_ua Thank you! Would you like to make an edit to add it as a note to the end? (Or should I)

Comment: Please do it, maybe add a link to another answer that worked in my case: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/42004/71752

Answer (score 8):

ImageMagick `compare -metric AE` exit status is non-zero if at least one pixel color differs.

Let’s say you have a folder named `before` which contains original images, and a folder `after` which should contain visually identical images with the same file name. Using [ImageMagick’s `compare`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php), you can do this:

```
for file in before/*.png; do
    result=$(compare -metric AE "${file}" "${file/before/after}" /tmp/diff.png 2>&1);
    if [ "${result}" != '0' ]; then
        echo "${result} incorrect pixels in ${file}";
    fi;
done;
```

Comment: Does this work on bioformat images like .TIF or .NDPI as far you know?

Comment: I found my answer here: https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php. So first step - which in the end is also fast enough for my purposes - is to convert to small png and compare these.

Answer (score 6):

If you have MATLAB, you can use:

```
% Reading images as array to variable 'a' & 'b'. 
a = imread('MIMICDatacollection.bmp'); 
b = imread('MIMICDatacollection.png'); 

% Flatten multidimensional arrays to 1D
c=a(:);
d=b(:);

% Perform comparison
if length(c) ~= length(d)
    disp('The images do not have the same size') 
else
    e = corr2(c,d);           
    if e==1 
        disp('The images are same')
    else 
        disp('The images are not same') 
    end; 
end
```

Personally, I use it with PNG and BMP, but it should work for any format supported by `imread`.

If you need to run it on a machine that doesn't have Matlab, you can turn it into a function  and compile it to make it CLI.

If you don't have Matlab that should be easy to port in any high-level language with a decent imaging library, such as Python Imaging Library (PIL).

Related:  [How can I tell if I am downloading/saving duplicate images?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7431/903)

Comment: Wouldn't something like `> 0.95` be better than `== 1` to compensate for compression artifacts in case of lossy compression?

Comment: @vsz I haven't tried it but that sounds reasonable.

Comment: @vsz Actually asker wants exactly the same graphically, so `== 1` is correct.

Answer (score 5):

[findimagedupes](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/) - Finds visually similar or duplicate images

> findimagedupes is a commandline utility which performs a rough "visual diff" to two images. This allows you to compare two images or a whole tree of images and determine if any are similar or identical. On common image types, findimagedupes seems to be around 98% accurate.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for my case as it reports visually similar (but not same) images as duplicates. I need it verify results of automated tests, so exact sameness is needed, not just similarity.

Answer (score 4):

I eventually created a small Qt program that I called imgdiff, which takes 2 filenames and performs a pixel-by-pixel comparison. It will print out an error message if they differ and exit with 1, or silently exit with 0 if they are the same.

Example usage would be:

```
imgdiff img1.png img2.bmp
```

Link to the Google Code project - https://code.google.com/p/imgdiff/.

Answer (score 2):

Try dupeguru from here: https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/.
In Picture mode it checks for similar images, even though they have different sizes, it has a threshold setting, creates groups of similar files, choosing the biggest file as main, but can be set another file for reference too. Is able to move files to some path or to the recycle bin or delete them completely. It is cross-platform.

Another interesting tool, that can be used for various merge operations too, is WinMerge: https://winmerge.org/. This has an interesting feature that highlights the difference areas in the images, but is able to compare up to three files at once, or three paths that contain files, but it compares the files having the same name only, if found on those paths. This is good for folder syncing. This is Windows only, runs fine in Wine, but there is a QT version available that seems to be in an early stage: https://github.com/OzzieIsaacs/winmerge-qt.

Comment: Can you add details on the relevant features of such software?

Answer (score 0):

Might need tweaking to handle alpha channel appropriately but converting to ppm and checksumming seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

find "${@:-.}" -type f -print |\
while IFS= read -r file; do
    hash=$(convert 2>&- "${file}" -strip ppm:- | md5sum) 
    # we get this hash if convert fails and produces no output
    [ "$hash" = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -' ] \
    || echo "$hash ${file}"
done |\
sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate | sed 's/^.\{36\}//'
```